# What is the correct way to convert/coerse a method with a self argument to a (thunk) 0-ary function in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function which requires a list of 0-ary functions (thunks),
but what I have are methods which are defined with the obligatory `self` as first argument, and sometimes additional arguments.

Here is what I'm doing.  Is this correct, or is there a better idiom?

What is the *correct* way to provide `self` and any additional arguments in one place, but call it elsewhere?

```py
    def canonicalize_once(self, nf=None):
        simplifiers = [lambda: self.conversion1(),
                       lambda: self.conversion2(),
                       lambda: self.conversion3(),
                       lambda: self.conversion4(),
                       lambda: self.conversion5(),
                       lambda: self.conversion6(),
                       lambda: self.conversion7(nf),
                       lambda: self.conversion8(),
                       lambda: self.conversion9(),
                       lambda: self.conversion10(),
                       lambda: self.conversion11(),
                       lambda: self.conversion12(),
                       lambda: self.conversion13(),
                       lambda: self.conversion14()]

        return find_simplifier(self, simplifiers)
```

Comment: This looks fine to a certain extent. Calling `simplifiers[6]()` will actually call `self.conversion7(nf)`. Seems to work.

Comment: When the methods have no additional argument other than `self` you don't have to use a lambda, just put `self.conversion1` without parentheses in the list.